# How to express a situation when a class teacher briefly and quickly mentions a section without full coverage

Tags: meaning

How to express a situation when a class teacher briefly and quickly mentions a section without full coverage.
What is the best word (verb & noun) for this situation. Is it called skim? This is compared to skip, in which no contents are mentioned.

Comment: What you mean is not clear at all.

Comment: If you mention a topic you typically don't give it any further coverage. For example, _The teacher mentioned that Napoleon was ill on the day of the battle_.  In any case, it would be unusual to say that _the teacher skimmed the battle of Austerlitz_. The term _skimming_ usually refers to a process of reading rather than speaking.

Answer (score 5):

**touch on/upon** (phrasal verb)

> To briefly talk or write about (something) : to mention (something)
> briefly
>
> *The reports touched on many important points.*
>
> *She touches upon the issue in the article but never fully explains it.*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch%20on)

**touch on**

> To mention a subject briefly or casually; treat of in passing
>
> *In his lecture he touched on the major aspects of the controversy.*
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/touch-on)

> Deal briefly with a subject in written or spoken discussion.
>
> *Her memoirs touch on her experiences in her long life.*
> [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=touch%20upon%20meaning)

Comment: +1, you may also say that *the teacher said a few words about ...*".

Answer (score 0):

**cruise through something**

Used to convey a sense of moving quickly or easily through something without getting too deeply involved

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying it:

> The teacher gave the topic only cursory attention.